# How to search a post by content or title on flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I 've wrote down routes and forms but after I searched it said "cannot found"
here's my code:

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def posts_lists():
  q = request.args.get('q')
  if q:
    posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.contains(q) | Post.content.contains(q))
  else:
    posts = Post.query.all()
    return render_template('search.html',posts=posts)
```

layout.html

```
<form method="POST" action="search">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" name="q">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

search.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% set page_title = 'Search' %}
{% block body %}
    <div>
        {{ render_form(url_for('search'), form) }} 
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any answer would be help!

Answer (score 0):

In your `<form>` you are using `method="POST"`
However, `q = request.args.get('q')` requires "GET"

Changing

```
<form method="POST" action="search">
```

to

```
<form method="GET" action="search">
```

should solve your problem.

Moreover, if `q` exists your routing function does not return a view. You need to un-indent your `return` so that the route always return a view with posts regardless of the value of q.

```py
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def posts_lists():
  q = request.args.get('q')
  if q:
    posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.contains(q) | Post.content.contains(q))
  else:
    posts = Post.query.all()
  return render_template('search.html',posts=posts)
```

Comment: Thanks again! I changed "POST" into "GET" and if I un-indent my return it shower wrong, so I code this:                                                                         @app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def posts_lists():
  q = request.args.get('q')
  if q:
    posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.contains(q) | Post.content.contains(q))
  else:
    posts = Post.query.all()
    return render_template('search.html',posts=posts)
  return render_template('search.html',posts=posts)

Comment: But when I searched, it direct into "search.html" but has nothing, is something gone wrong?

Comment: Hi. Firstly, I have edited my answer to make my suggestion clearer. Secondly, i am not sure how your `layout.html` look like and how `render_form()` works, so I am unable to give any suggestions using the given information. I suggest doing it step by step and find guidance in [flask doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)